Calculating the convection coefficient of a green roof
as part of a course I have to calculate heat transfer through a green roof. I'm using Python to carry out an assessment over twenty years. The data I have are irradiance, wind speed, air temperature, temperature under foliage and temperature at 20cm in the ground.
I'm a bit lost in my calculation of the external transfer coefficient I need to calculate the global. I can't work out the surface temperature of the green roof. Can I assume that this is equal to the temperature under the foliage? How do I go about obtaining this information? Is there a formula that only takes wind speed into account and doesn't require knowing the surface temperature?
Thank you very much for your answers.

So what are the units of the convection coefficient?
